# how to check list which has tab characters in it in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a data.csv file with belwo content in it and at the end of this file, it has some new lines as well. Now I want to read this file and get the value from last row for particular column.

```
Connecting to the ControlService endpoint

Found 3 rows.
Requests List:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Client ID                                                                   | Client Type                  | Service Type | Status               | Trust Domain              | Data Instance Name | Data Version | Creation Time              | Last Update                | Scheduled Time | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 REFRESH_ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS_1465901168866                              | ROUTINGTIER_ARTIFACTS | SYSTEM       | COMPLETED            | RRA Bulk Client    | soa_server1       | 18.2.2.0.0  | 2016-06-14 03:49:55 -07:00 | 2016-06-14 03:49:57 -07:00 | ---            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 500333443                                                          | CREATE                        | [FA_GSI]     | COMPLETED            | holder       | soa_server1       | 18.3.2.0.0  | 2018-08-07 11:59:57 -07:00 | 2018-08-07 12:04:37 -07:00 | ---            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 500333446                                                          | CREATE                        | [FA_GSI]     | COMPLETED            | holder-test  | soa_server1       | 18.3.2.0.0  | 2018-08-07 12:04:48 -07:00 | 2018-08-07 12:08:52 -07:00 | ---            | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to parse the above file and extra value from the last row. I want to extra value of "Client ID" and "Trust Domain" column in the last row which is:

```
Client ID: 500333446
Trust Domain: holder-test
```

I got my below python script but it fails because of new lines at the end of the csv file? If my csv file doesnt have any new line then it works fine.

```
import csv

lines_to_skip = 4
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for i in range(lines_to_skip):
        next(reader)

    data = []
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].find("---") != 0:
            print line
            data.append(line)

print("{}={}".format(data[-1][0].replace(" ",""),data[-1][4].replace(" ","")))
```

I am getting this error at if block line if my csv file has some new lines at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    if line[0].find("---") != 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the line prints out at the end:

```
[' \t\t']
```

Comment: actually I am saving output of another script in a .csv file so thats why it is like this

Comment: I think you don't need to use `csv` module for your task. Just parse this file as usual with simple splits by `|` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try splitting each row with `|` into a list of dictionaries and only printing the `Client ID` and `Trust Domain` from the last row:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:

    # collect rows of interest
    rows = []
    for line in f:
        if '|' in line:
            items = [item.strip() for item in line.split('|')]
            rows.append(items)

    # first item will be headers
    headers = rows[0]

    # put each row into dictionary
    data = [dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in rows[1:]]

    # print out last row information of interest
    print('Client ID:', data[-1]['Client ID'])
    print('Trust Domain:', data[-1]['Trust Domain'])
```

Which Outputs:

```
Client ID: 500333446
Trust Domain: holder-test
```

As requested in the comments, if you want to print `500333446=holder-test` instead, you can change the final print sequence to:

```
print('%s=%s' % (data[-1]['Client ID'], data[-1]['Trust Domain']))
# 500333446=holder-test
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have empty lines at the end, the `csv.reader` will give you empty rows, so you have to write code to deal with that. If you just do `line[0]` on every line, even the empty ones, you will get exactly the exception you're asking about.

But all you have to do is check whether `line` is empty before trying to check `line[0]`:

```
if line:
    if line[0].find("---") != 0:
```

… or, more compactly:

```
if line and line[0].find("---") != 0:
```

Comment: it still doesn't work as I already tried before with strip as well. I think line is a list here and at the end of the line this is what it prints out `[' \t\t']`

Comment: @flash Of course `strip` isn't going to work on a list. But `if line` will. It's true if the list is non-empty, and false if it's empty. And `line[0].find("---"))` will not raise an `IndexError` if `line` is `[' \t\t']`. `line[0]` is perfectly legal, and means `' \t\t'`, and `line[0].find("---")` is perfectly legal, and returns `-1`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still get same error.

Comment: @flash Also, if your code printed out `[' \t\t']`, then that line didn't have a problem. It's the _next_ line, after that one. Because if you get the `IndexError`, you never get to the `print`.

Comment: @flash You need to give us a [mcve] that can reproduce the problem. What I showed will work for the problem you described. So presumably the problem you actually have is not the problem you described. Which means nobody can guess how to debug it.

Comment: aah I see.. so how can I fix this? I have a csv file which has new lines at the end with some tabs in them.. thats all I have in a file

Comment: @flash Again, what I showed you will solve the problem you're describing. If it doesn't solve your actual problem, you have to show us your actual problem. Please read the [mcve] link I gave you, and [edit] your question into something that reproduces the problem you need debugged.

Answer (score -1):

Before processing the line, you should `strip` off any unwanted characters and verify that it is a line that you want.

What you can do is this:

```
if line and line[0].strip(" \t") and not line[0].startswith("---"):
```

Or another way:

```
if all([line, line[0].strip(" \t"), not line[0].startswith("---")]):
```

1. `if line` checks if the `line` is an empty list, so that 2. does not throw an error.
2. `line[0].strip(" \t")` checks if the first value only contains unwanted characters.
3. `not line[0].startswith("---")` is the same as your `line[0].find("---") != 0`

Comment: First, this is trying to solve a totally different problem from the one the OP asked about. Doing `line[0].strip(" \t")` won't affect an `IndexError` from `line[0]`.

Comment: yes this works for some reason. I tried first suggestion and it works fine.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, `line[0].strip(" \t")` does not solve the problem OP is asking about, but it does solve a problem he will may have in the future -- having unwanted data in the `data` list.

Comment: Also, there's no point stripping the string to test that it has any non-whitespace characters. `line[0].find('---')` will already not be 0 for `''` or `'\t'` any more than it will for `'\t---'`.

Comment: @MoonCheesez No, it doesn't solve that problem either. Strings that are all blank will return `-1` for the `line[0].find("---")` that he already has. You're just adding more code that doesn't do anything extra.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, so if `line[0]` is `" \t"`, it will pass `not line[0].startswith("---")`. So I would like to exclude the `" \t"` characters as well by stripping

Comment: @MoonCheesez Why? You're _already_ excluding that line, so why write another test that doesn't add anything?

Comment: @abarnert The thing is that `not line[0].startswith("---")` does not exclude `" \t"` because `" \t"` does not start with `"---"`. So `not line[0].startswith("---")` will be `True` for `" \t"`